# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException in Java 8

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, java-8

The application was working fine in Java 6 with spring 2.5.6 libraries. But I was getting library errors in Java 8. I am trying to upgrade the application to Java 8 on Tomcat 9, hence updated the libraries to 3.2.1.

This is my application context file:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
       <property name="dataSource"><ref local="dataSource"/></property>
       <!--<property name="lobHandler"><ref local="oracleLobHandler"/></property>-->
       <property name="packagesToScan">
           <list>
             <value>net.abc.acs.domain</value>
           </list>
       </property>
       <property name="annotatedPackages">
           <list>
             <value>net.abc.acs.domain</value>
           </list>
       </property>
</bean>
```

I see this error now:

```
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
> resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet.init(ContextLoaderServlet.java:81)
>   at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1117)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4958)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5265)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:690)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:538)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1690)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor77.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
>   at
> com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>   at
> com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1614)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:1026)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:357)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670)     at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:660)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:378)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:56)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
> org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)    at
> org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)    at
> org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)    at
> org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
>   at
> org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
>   at
> org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
>   at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.scanPackages(AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.java:191)
>   at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.postProcessMappings(AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.java:174)
>   at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:672)
>   at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
>   at org.springframewo
```

Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks